# Multi column filter in DataTables(bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the `DataTables` API for my table in the application. I have a scenario where I want multiple columns be enabled for filtering purpose.

I have this code setup now. But it only searches for `Column2`. Even if I enter value for `Column1` it doesn't search.

```
    $('#btnFilter').click(function () {
        table.fnFilter($('#Column1').val());
        table.fnFilter($('#Column2').val());
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

i guess `fnFilter` will also accepts `iColumn` paramter

so try using like this

```
table.fnFilter($('#Column1').val(), 0);  //0 is the first column
table.fnFilter($('#Column2').val(), 1);
```